# Php - Performing an action once. Else, perform other action

Tags: php

I know this is basic but I couldn't find a post in SO that would answer my question. Basically, I want to know if I have the following code:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $check++;
    if ($check==1)
    {
        echo "bla";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "hey";
    }
}
```

How can I make sure it prints `blaheyheyheyheyheyheyheyheyhey` without give me the following error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: check in **[...][...]** on line **4**
>   blaheyheyheyheyheyheyheyheyhey

I know that the variable `$count` isn't defined, but if I define it such as doing `$count = 0;`, I will never be able to generate the desired outcome since it would always return the value of `$count` to 0 and never increment it.

By the way, the code needs to remain INSIDE the loop not outside!

Comment: You need to define `$check` before using it - and that's outside the loop - or it will be defined again every iteration. Or better yet, just use `$i`.

Comment: use `$i` without `$check`

Comment: When the `for` loop finishes, you will have last value `$i` was, in this case would be `9`. And remember that you are not getting and **error**, you are getting a **warning**. They are not the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notice is simply saying that $check is not defined before being referenced. The best thing to do would be to declare `$check = 0` before entering the loop. But if it MUST be inside the loop, then you can use `isset()` and set $check if it is not set.

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
        if (!isset($check))
        {
            $check = 0;
        }

        $check++;
        if ($check==1)
        {
            echo "bla";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "hey";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The solution by @Omi is the ideal way to solve this problem - you shouldn't need to introduce new variables (ie $check) for something as simple as this.

Comment: No. You're answer is the right one. I already knew about the solution of @Omi and it's not the one for my program.

Comment: @TedIdzikowski Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you don't want to rely on `$i`? Both $i and $check get incremented by 1 with every iteration through the for loop, so $i and $check will always be the same value.

Comment: It's because I will be using it for a data entry system. And I won't be using a counter loop just like above. Your solution works without the for loop. It works by just repeating the action. Let's say I enter data once, then it does a certain action. Then after that time, when I try to enter data another time, it does the other action.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Yo dont need extra variable to check just check for `$i`

```
 <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
            {
                if ($i==0)
                {
                    echo "bla";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "hey";
                }
            }

    ?>
```

Output:  `blaheyheyheyheyheyheyheyheyhey`

Comment: No this isn't what I wanted.

Comment: It ll gives you desired output

Comment: Exactly what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

you can define $check before for loop .

```
    $check=0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
        $check++;
        if ($check==1)
        {
            echo "bla";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "hey";
        }
    }
```